# Drupal Calendar - Calendar View not displaying entries in IE7

Tags: css, drupal, calendar, html-table

I'm using a Drupal Calendar and it's working well in all browsers except IE7. In IE7, the individual calendar entries do not render.

The weird thing is, if the page loads slowly then the correctly coloured table cells appear and then disappear.

Here is a list of the things I've tried:

- Updated to latest version of Calendar
- Updated to latest version of Views
- Set CSS Display properties on the inner coloured divs
- Removed all JQuery and Javascript in-case it's interfering

I'm out of ideas as to why this is happening!
I'm asking here as opposed to Drupal Stack Exchange because I believe it's a CSS/HTML issue with IE7 not Drupal Exclusively.

Here's my Litmus Output - every browser even IE6 is displaying it correctly:

[image]

Comment: pls provide the link to the page also are you using devel on ur site ? that sometimes can be a problem

Comment: Hi, can't provide a link for the page because I cant reveal it's contents for the benefit of the client. I've fixed it now anyway, I'll post the solution.

Comment: great , looking forward to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Okay, because this issue was so restricted to IE7, I researched issues related exclusively to IE7 and found out about the dreaded `hasLayout` property.

So I was able to create a conditional stylesheet and apply the following css to any affected entries:

```
{
    zoom:1;
}
```

Fixed.
Also, I hate Microsoft.